# Adding <base> tag href with Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, radix

The HTML base-tag is used to specify a default URL and a default target for all links on a page. The domain of my angular page is dynamic (test, production etc.).

Since IE9 and IE10 don't seem to support relative path's like "app/", but need it to be absolute, a solution is needed to specify correct base "href".

I am trying to add the following without success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<base href='http://localhost:8080/app/' />");
</script>
```

It generates the same DOM markup as "hard-coding" it like this:

```
<base href='http://localhost:8080/app/' />
```

The hardcoded version does work in all browsers tested but the JavaScript version does not. It actually ONLY work in IE9 (according to my test).

My guess is that any base-tag is "parsed" *before* any JS has been run, and this is why the browser don't apply it to the links, because it can't find it at that point...This is just a thesis however.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all responses. I found a solution that works in my case, and the important thing was to not add the BASE-tag itself with JavaScript, instead *only* modify the href attrubute. If I added the tag with JavaScript it wouldn't work in most browsers for my solution. The following code modifies the href value with JavaScript to make it absolute based on current domain and it works fine in both Chrome and IE9...

```html
<head>
  <base href="app/" />
  <script>
    (function() {
      // Fetch base element and href attribute
      var baseElement = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0];
      var currentBaseHrefValue = baseElement.getAttribute('href');

      // Get correct domain value
      var urlForBase = window.location.href;
      var urlForBaseArr = urlForBase.split('/');
      var baseHrefUrl = urlForBaseArr[0] + '//' + urlForBaseArr[2] + '/' + currentBaseHrefValue;

      // Update base with domain to make it absolute for IE9 and IE10
      baseElement.setAttribute("href", baseHrefUrl);
    }());
  </script>
</head>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Additionally to make it work in IE9 it would be for the best to add an end tag to the base-tag: <base href="app/" ></base>

Answer (score 2):

I think that BASE tag should be used in HEAD, instead of BODY.
So you should append BASE in his right place.

[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

```
var base = document.createElement('base');
base.href = 'http://www.w3.org/';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(base);
```

That should solve problems.

Comment: This would be a better link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: Hi, I have tried that approach as well (appending with javascript instead of using document.write) and I am actually putting it in the head-tag exactly in the same way I am adding it the hard-coded way.

Comment: Sorry then. When I was testing it, document.write had added base to body.
Maybe you should try run script with async or defer (if it is really caused by parsing).

Answer (score 1):

To add to @SkyWookie 's answer, when placing the `<base>` at the head, you should place it before any other elements which isn't that easy with plain JS. The function `prepend(elem, host)` is for such occasions.

**Note:** Tested in this snippet it doesn't look like it works. If you want to see it work, go here: http://plnkr.co/edit/J4XH6UYeKSilOxCu86De?p=preview .

In order to see the base inserted properly, you must do the following:

1. Right click on the page.
2. Pick Inspect.
3. Pick the Elements tab.
4. Locate the `<head>` and verify if the first element inside the `<head>` is the `<base>`

```js
var baseHref = document.querySelector('base').href;

function prepend(elem, host) {
  var host = document.querySelector(host);
  var elem = document.createElement(elem);
  host.insertBefore(elem, host.firstChild);
}

//Usage

prepend('base', 'head');
baseHref = "https://example.com";
```

```html
<!doctype>
<html>

<head>
  <!---------------------------------<base> should go there-->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>DynamicBase</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style></style>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -5):

Try to use JQuery and $().ready() function, which is called only once the page loading has been completed.

Comment: Why would waiting help? This answer smacks of cargo-cultism.

Comment: If the base tag do not work, then js libraries won't be able to load. Therefore at least in my solution I need to get base-tag to work before using any frameworks like jQuery. And the whole point of the base-tag is put to use before page load.